# Getting stack difference in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I was checking this chart library highcharts.. I was wondering how does it show in this example http://jsfiddle.net/wvT85/ the stackTotal in the tooltip option and is it possible to get a difference instead of total:

```
    $(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of fruits'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                    'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
            stack: 'male2'
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
            stack: 'male2'
        }]
      });
     });

  });
```

Comment: Difference between stacks or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stackTotal` is Highcharts API to total the value on the basis of `stackKey` i.e. `the name of stack given`. These APIs are undocumented and do not appear on the official site.

For finding the difference use this:

```
'Diff: '+ Math.abs(this.point.stackTotal-this.y);
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/androdify/wvT85/70/

Also, for better control over the tooltip, see shared tooltip formatter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip

Comment: Thannnnkss... This was what i needed =]